# What plugin manager allows installing plugins from tags

Tags: plugin-managers

I am searching for a plugin manager that has the option to install specific plugins only from tags on GitHub. I don't want to need to specify the tag. I want it to automatically use the newest tag. This would be a good option for plugins that do not keep a stable master branch, but do tag releases.

Comment: Why ask random strangers when you can read their documentation and decide for yourself?

Comment: @romainl You could apply that logic to any question asked anywhere on here. I did look through the documentation for some plugin managers. So far I have not found what I want. I am seeing if anybody knows of a manager that will satisfy my needs.

Comment: Indeed, good, well researched, questions are not really the hallmark of this site.

Comment: [`vim-plug`'s  README](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) says you can specify tags. Another way would be to setup a script that gets the latest tag and does a `git checkout` on it (using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404796/how-to-get-the-latest-tag-name-in-current-branch-in-git), and using it as a post-update script in `vim-plug`.

Comment: @muru Good idea! I will have to try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current version of vim-plug allows you to specify tags with wildcards and it selects the latest version (`--sort -version:refname`) if multiple matching tags are found. So you can simply write `*` if you want the latest tag. For example,

```
Plug 'fatih/vim-go', { 'tag': '*' }
```

And you'll see that the installer handles it as expected.

```
- Finishing ... Done!
- Latest tag for * -> v1.7.1 (vim-go)
- vim-go: Cloning into '/Users/jg/.vim/plugged/vim-go'...
```